# jQuery plugins to create a hovering div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I would like to create a hovering div on the right hand side similar to this page: https://www.feedbackify.com/ and when someone click, it will create an ajax pop up. Is there any jQuery plugin to do this? If not, can you guide me which tool should I use to make this to happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the developer tools to inspect the html and css they are using for that tab. It can be done easily without a plugin. For the modal there are many jQuery libraries that you can choose from.

Here is a basic example I made in jsfiddle using the bootstrap modal plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/uq7f1163/7/

Hope it helps.

**CSS:**

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
#feedback {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right 0;
}
#feedback button {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="feedback">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome! Make sure you take note of the external resources I loaded into jsfiddle. There is an external bootstrap js file and an external bootstrap css file.